# Stopwatch pause/resume button

Tags: ios, nstimer

I have a NSTimer working as a stopwatch. And I want to have it so I can pause and resume it using the same button. I have tried to use a BOOL but I have had no luck.

```
-(IBAction)pause:(id)sender {

    if (running == true) {
        [myticker invalidate]; {

        } else if(running == false) {
            myticker = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.01 target:self selector:@selector(showActivity) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
        }
      }
}

-(IBAction)start:(id)sender {
    running=true;
    baseDate = [NSDate date];
    myticker = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.01 target:self selector:@selector(showActivity) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)showActivity {
    NSTimeInterval interval = [baseDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
    double intpart;
    double fractional = modf(interval, &intpart);
    NSUInteger hundredth = ABS((int)(fractional*100));
    NSUInteger seconds = ABS((int)interval);
    NSUInteger minutes = seconds/60;
    NSUInteger hours = minutes/60;
    time.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes%60, seconds%60, hundredth];
}
```

Comment: Just FYI, printing `NSUIntegers` doesn't work with `%d`.

Answer (score 0):

You kinda complicated everything.

You can simply nil out your timer when you invalidate it and then you can check if he exists or not. Additionally what you are doing can create several timers running since I believe you can press the start several times before you press pause.

You can do something like this:

```
-(IBAction)start:(id)sender {
    if(!myticker) {    
        baseDate = [NSDate date];
        myticker = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.01 
                                                    target:self
                                                  selector:@selector(showActivity)
                                                  userInfo:nil 
                                                   repeats:YES];
    }
 }

-(IBAction)pause:(id)sender {
    if(!myticker)
       myticker = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.01 
                                                    target:self
                                                  selector:@selector(showActivity)
                                                  userInfo:nil 
                                                   repeats:YES];
    else {
        [myticker invalidate];
        myticker = nil;
    }
}
```

Note that sending an invalidate message to a myticker that is nil will do nothing. Additionally, this way, you avoid scheduling more timers than necessary and if the user presses start multiple times you just ignore it.

Comment: So with this code, how would I resume the stopwatch from when I pressed pause?

Comment: You want to resume also when you press pause again ?

Comment: I have edited my answer to do that case. BOOLs are legal but they usually are some sort of code smell. You don't need them in this scenario :)

Comment: The label display pauses but when I resume, it seems that the timer just carried on. I.E it actually hasn't stopped the timer. This is really confusing me :P